# Default placeholder value in spring xml

Tags: xml, spring, hibernate, placeholder

In our specific application db.properties file is provided by 3d party. Dependent on configuration, this property file could contain db.schema property or not. So, if there is no db.schema property, the db.username must be used for hibernate.default_schema property.

The placeholder ${db.schema:db.username} does not retrieve value of db.username if db.schema does not exist, so that 'db.schema' value is propagated instead of actual (i.e. dba) one.

So, the question is: how to propagate default value of db.username if db.schema does not exist (lets assume that db.username always exists) ?

```
<util:properties id="specificHibernateProperties">
    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.default_schema">${db.schema:db.username}</prop>
</util:properties>
```

Answer (score 6):

In Spring 3, it should be possible to use nested placeholders.
So please try this:

```
${db.schema:${db.username}}
```

/rgrds

Comment: I was skeptical but I tried this and it actually works.  Nice!